# How to insert jQuery event value into array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The structure of quantity element:
/*within for loop*/

    
     
    
    
   

/*within for loop*/

As you see above,  input[name=qty] is accompanied by input[name=qty2[]]. All I need to do is, as value keyed into input[name=qty], that value must be stored inside its pair of input[name=qty2[]] as well. Because when submitting this form, I will need all values of qty and thats why I need qty2[] an array to keep them all.

EDIT:

This does what I want but **doesn't total up value for total qty and total amount.**

Declared array before $.each loop

```
var collectQty = [];
```

Within $.each loop

```
collectQty.push(product_quantity);
```

Outside $.each loop

```
var qty2 = collectQty.join(", ");
         $('input[id^='+param+'_qty2]').val().push(qty2);
```

This shows the following. NOTE:The wider textbox is qty2[]

[image]

Comment: it's really hard to understand what you're after here.  can you clarify please?

Comment: @billynoah, I need to store values of input[name=qty] into input[name=qty2[] as they are keyed in.

Comment: @billynoah, I edited my post, see if you can understand better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you could do something simple like this:

```
<td class='qty_"+data[i].id+"'>
    <input type='text' name='qty' style='width:50px;height:20px;margin:10px auto;' value='' onchange='$(this).next(\"input\").val(this.value); subTotal2(\""+data[i].id+"\")'>
    <input type='hidden' id = '"+data[i].id+"_qty2[]' name='qty2[]' value=''>
```

Might be better to put stuff like this in a `<script>` block though:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[name=qty]').on('input', function() {
        $(this).next('input').val(this.value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Its taking latest value for all qty2[]